# SQL divide by zero error - ISNULL not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query I am working on that does some math, specifically totals and percentages. Due to this data being optional based on the date range selected, there are times where theres nothing that it can run this math against.

I am getting a divide by zero error in this instance.

```
    SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(s.ScoreID) AS TotalSamples,
                 COUNT(CASE WHEN qd.QDResultDesc = 'Pass' THEN 1 END) AS Pass,
                 COUNT(CASE WHEN qd.QDResultDesc = 'Pass' THEN 1 END) * 100 / COUNT(s.ScoreID) AS Quality,
                 COUNT(CASE WHEN qd.QDResultDesc = 'Fail' THEN 1 END) AS Fail,
                 COUNT(CASE WHEN qd.QDResultDesc = 'Fail' THEN 1 END) * 100 / COUNT(s.ScoreID) AS Error
            FROM SubmissionScore AS s
            JOIN gSubmission AS sub
            ON sub.SubmissionID = s.RecordID
            JOIN gQDResult AS qd
            ON s.QDResultID = qd.QDResultID
            JOIN resources.emp.Employees as e
            ON sub.TeammateQID = e.QID
            WHERE e.CampusID = 66 -- Chennai
        FOR    XML PATH ('overall'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT ('chennai')
    )
FOR    XML PATH ('data'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT ('root');
```

I have tried adding `ISNULL` to account for missing pieces but that doesn't seem to fix it.

In the query above, if there is no data, I would expect the output to just be `0`.

Is there an easy way to tweak this code to account for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `NULLIF()`, not `ISNULL()`:

```
            COUNT(CASE WHEN qd.QDResultDesc = 'Pass' THEN 1 END) * 100 / NULLIF(COUNT(s.ScoreID), 0) AS Quality,
```

You may also want `* 100.0`, because SQL Server does integer arithmetic.